# TextView via addView() in LinearLayout not adding correctly

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm currently having issues getting ***addView()*** to work correctly, it's creating the text inside the ***LinearLayout*** as plain text, but not in the ***TextView()*** that i'm creating programatically to add into the ***LL*** itself.

I've used the ***Component Tree*** to see this happen during running the app on my device.

**Fragment.kt**

```
    package com.test.testapp
    
    import android.os.Bundle
    import android.util.Log
    import android.view.LayoutInflater
    import android.view.View
    import android.view.ViewGroup
    import android.widget.LinearLayout
    import android.widget.TextView
    import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
    
    class DashboardFragment : Fragment() { 
        override fun onCreateView(
            inflater: LayoutInflater,
            container: ViewGroup?,
            savedInstanceState: Bundle?
        ): View? {
            val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_dashboard, container, false)
            getUpdateList()
    
            return view
        }
    
    
        override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
            super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        }
    
        fun getUpdateList(){
            val testinglayout : LinearLayout = requireView().findViewById(R.id.testinglayout)
            val textView = TextView(activity)
    
            textView.setText("Test")
            testinglayout.addView(textView)
        }
    }
```

**Fragment.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/rmPaleTeal"
        tools:context=".DashboardFragment">
    
        <ScrollView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:background="@color/rmPaleTeal"
            android:padding="15dp">
    
            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">
                
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/dashboard_latest_title"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="Latest Updates"
                    android:textColor="@color/rmDarkBlue"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />
    
                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/testinglayout"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/dashboard_latest_title"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                </LinearLayout>
    
            </RelativeLayout>
    
        </ScrollView>
    
    </RelativeLayout>
```

**Ref Image (Component Tree)**
[image: Component tree reference]

Any help would be greatly appreciated, as i'm a little lost, and can't seem to find the right answers online to address it.

Thank you for your time!

Comment: Can you please clarify what "creating the text inside the LinearLayout as plain text" means? What exactly are you seeing in the Component Tree? A LinearLayout can only contain other views or containers, it can't store "plain text" which is not rendered by any view.

Comment: Hi @Egor, that's what's confusing me, typically it displays text as it's own element but it's being lumped onto the LL. I've edited my post to include a ref image, hopefully that'll give you a picture of what's happening.

Comment: There are some issues 1st is this you might not getting view by using requireView() instead of doing this store the view in class instead of function and 2nd is the layout params of textview you can also check the layout by turning on layout bounds in developer options of your device

Answer (score 1):

This issue is Android Studio itself, i'm currently using Hedgehog for note, but it's unable to recompile the Component Tree view if you add in programatically, which makes the new elements uninspectable, so you don't know what's truly there, just have to assume your programatic layout additions are correct.

I hope they fix this in the future, as there doesn't seem to be a refresh/update CT feature anywhere. Thank you to anyone that spent you time looking at this, much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I think you have not defined layout params for the textview you created dynamically.

You can do this by :

```
fun getUpdateList(){
            val testinglayout : LinearLayout = requireView().findViewById(R.id.testinglayout)
            val textView = TextView(activity)
            val params = LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                    LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                    LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
                )
            textView.setText("Test")
            textView.layoutParams = params
            testinglayout.addView(textView)
        }
```

You can even add more customizations so that you can see the changes in you textview like this:

```
                textView.setTextColor(
                   ResourcesCompat.getColor(resources,R.color.white,null)
                 )
                textView.setPadding(20,10,20,10)
                textView.background = 
                ResourcesCompat.getDrawable
                (resources,R.drawable.textView_background,null)
                textView.textSize = 20f
```

Hope this helps you in your project and i would be happy to help you more.

Comment: Hey there, thank you for your time and chippin in. I've resolved it, basically it looks like Android Studio doesn't recompile it's Component Tree if you add in programatically, which is a little unintuitive, so you have to do guess work to some degree, as it's uninspectable due to no recompiling of the view.